# Optimizing Dynamic Database Connection Switching in Laravel 6.20.44 with AWS RDS Cluster for Read and Write Operations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I'm working on a Laravel application, specifically using Laravel Framework 6.20.44 and PHP 7.2. In my AWS environment, I have a cluster with two RDS instances—one for read operations and another for write operations.
My goal is to dynamically switch between these database connections based on query types in my Laravel application.

Proposed Solution:

- Configuration: I've configured two separate database connections
  (mysql for writing and mysql_read for reading) in
  config/database.php.
- Dynamic Connection Switch: In my code, I'm using Laravel's DB facade
  to explicitly switch between the read and write connections based on
  the query type. For instance, I utilize the read connection for
  SELECT queries and the write connection for INSERT, UPDATE, and
  DELETE queries.
- Concerns: While my current approach works, I'm cautious about the
  performance impact, especially regarding the use of DB::disconnect().
  I'd like to optimize this database connection-switching process
  without compromising performance.

**What are the recommended strategies and best practices for dynamically switching between read and write database connections in Laravel without incurring performance issues, particularly regarding the use of DB::disconnect()? Are there alternative approaches or optimizations I should consider to achieve this database connection switching while maintaining good performance?**

```
class DatabaseServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        DB::listen(function (QueryExecuted $query) {
            if ($this->isReadQuery($query->sql)) {
                DB::disconnect();
                config(['database.default' => 'mysql_read']);
            } else {
                config(['database.default' => 'mysql_write']);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Check if the query is a SELECT query.
     *
     * @param  string  $sql
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isReadQuery($sql)
    {
        return str_starts_with(strtolower($sql), 'select');
    }
}
```

config/app.php

```
  'providers' => [
    ...,
    App\Providers\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    ]
```

My database connection
config/database.php

```
'mysql_write' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_HOST_WRITE', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  'strict' => true,
  'engine' => 'InnoDB',
]

'mysql_read' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_HOST_READ', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  'strict' => true,
  'engine' => 'InnoDB',
],
```

Comment: Both Laravel v6 and PHP 7.2 are out of support since months (for Laravel) and years (for PHP). Please update them. Also, please share whether this is a PHP problem, a MySQL problem, or an AWS problem. There's also some documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#read-and-write-connections, did you check that?

Comment: Hello Nico,
While I don't have a specific issue right now, I'm seeking best practices for efficiently handling database connections in a high-traffic application. Unfortunately, due to project constraints, I can't upgrade PHP or Laravel at this time.
If you have any insights or recommendations for optimizing database connection switching within these limitations, I'd appreciate your input.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you check the documentation I've linked to?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it now. If I add the following configuration:

'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => [
            '192.168.1.1',
            '196.168.1.2',
        ],
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => [
            '196.168.1.3',
         ],
    ],
...
],
Will this configuration automatically switch the database based on whether it's a read or write operation?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, why not try it out and see what happens? I would assume that Laravel's core features either work properly, or it's time to file a bug report with them